# Running Matlab .m file with arguments in a bash script

Tags: bash, matlab, variables

I have a Matlab .m file that takes three input arguments:

> calculate('input.txt','Alex','output.txt')

I would like to run this .m file in a shell script as follows:

> matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -r "run
> calculate('input.txt','Alex','output.txt)"

Unfortunately, this did not work. I get the following error:

> Error using run (line 70)
>
> calculate('input.txt','Alex','output.txt') not
> found.

Any pointer as to how I can give the input arguments/variables?

Thanks.

Note: The following did not work either - complaining too many arguments.

> matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -r "run calculate input.txt Alex output.txt"

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to remove `run`. `run` is for scripts, not for functions (and anyway it's not necessary unless you need to specify the script's path). So, try

```
matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -r "calculate('input.txt','Alex','output.txt')"
```

If your function `calculate` is not in Matlab's path, change to its folder first. For example

```
matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -r "cd 'c:\users\Alex\SomeFolder'; calculate('input.txt','Alex','output.txt')"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I modified as you suggest. Now I get the following error: Undefined function 'calculate' for input arguments of type 'char'. ps: Typing in both ways works fine in the command line.

Comment: That's probably because `calculate` is not in Matlab's path. Put it in some folder Matlab sees by default (any folder included in `path`)

Comment: I tried this and did not work: -r "addpath('/path-to-m-file/'; calculate('input.txt','Alex','output.txt')"

Comment: It should be `"addpath('/path-to-m-file/'); calculate('input.txt','Alex','output.txt')"` (missing `)`)

Comment: Try `matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -r "addpath '/some/folder'; disp('test');"` and see if that works

Comment: Yes, it changes the directory correctly, and then prints test.

Comment: Now replace only `disp('test')` by `calculate('input.txt','Alex','output.txt')`. If it doesn't work, it's something with your `calculate` function

Comment: Okay - it now complains: Undefined function 'calculate' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Comment: It complains about undefined function, however, when I check "which calculate", it correctly find the location where calculate.m resides.